# How to get dragged and dropped row ids?

Tags: jquery, jquery-droppable

I have two tables, where I should be able to drag and drop row from any one to other. While dropping I have to get the values of dropped row's columns and do some addition and subtraction to some of the column values. Below is what I'm trying (Pardon me if my code looks bad as I'm still learning jQuery). Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" > 
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
$(function() {
    setupDragDrop($('#t1 tr'), $('#t2 tr'));
    setupDragDrop($('#t2 tr'), $('#t1 tr'));
});
function setupDragDrop(source, target) {
    source.draggable({
        revert: false,
        opacity: .75,
        containment: '.container',
        cursor: 'move',
        cursorAt: {
            top: 35,
            left: 45
        },
        helper: function(event) {
            return $('<div class="drag-row"><table></table></div>').find('table').append($(event.target).closest('tr').clone()).end();
        },
        appendTo: 'body',
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            //this.drop();
        }
    });
    target.droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) { //I tried many code here nothing works
        },
        accept: source.selector
    });
}
$(function() {
    $("[name=toggler]").click(function() {
        $('.toHide').hide();
        $("#blk-" + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
</script>​
```

Comment: Hi, The jsfiddle.net link is http://jsfiddle.net/8MwAf/2/. When I drop I have to add source number of bundles to target column value and so on. Not sure how to achieve it?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include jQuery library. Please try now http://jsfiddle.net/8MwAf/3/

Comment: Still cant drag from one table to the other ?

Comment: did you try with the new link with update http://jsfiddle.net/8MwAf/3/?

Comment: Hi, Any directions for me please?